# How to get custom attributes on .to_json method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

For example, i've this model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def foo
    bar
  end

end
```

When i do this:
    <%= User.all.to_json %>

I get this:

[{"user":{"created_at":"2011-06-07T17:40:21-03:00","login":"abcd", "password":"1234","updated_at":"2011-06-07T18:10:04-03:00"}}]

How can i get foo on this json too? Also, foo is an activerecord too..

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
User.all.to_json(:methods => :foo)
```

It may also be useful to limit the attributes that are sent, you can do this with either the `:only` and `:except` options. e.g. It is unlikely you will want the password in this data.