# ActiveRecord custom attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a 3 simple models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many    :subscriptions
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many    :subscriptions
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :user
    belongs_to  :game
end
```

What I am wondering is, is it possible when I query for Games to include another attribute called 'is_subbed' which will contain wether a particular user is subscribed to a game? Something like:

```
a_user = User.first

games = Game.scoped
games.conditions blah blah blah
```

and games will include a 'virtual' or in memory attribute that will be custom to a_user called is_subed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a class method and an instance method (for a single game) like so:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.subscribed?(user)
    joins(:subscriptions).where(subscriptions: { user_id: user.id}).exists?
  end

  def subscribed?(user)
    subscriptions.where(user_id: user.id).exists?
  end
end
```

To get this result for each game using the query API, you can do this:

```
scope :with_subscriptions, lambda do |user|
  joins("LEFT JOIN subscriptions ON subscriptions.game_id = games.id AND subscriptions.user_id = #{user.id}")
  select("games.*, CASE WHEN subscriptions.user_id IS NULL THEN true ELSE false END as is_subscribed")
end
```

This will give you an `is_subscribed` parameter on each game object returned.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I need to be part of a large number of scoped conditions and returned via json in one query

Comment: @0xSina: `games.subscribed?(user)` will return true or false depending on if the user is subscribed to any of the games.  It will do this in one query.  Are you looking for a different result?  Perhaps you mean to return for each game if a user is subscribed?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am looking for. That's why I am doing Game.scoped to get a bunch of games that match some conditions, along with them include some sort of attribute that indicates wether all the games returned are subscribed by a particular user. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: For some reason it's not working. It doesn't include 'is_subscribed' key when I convert the results to json

Comment: @0xSina: This is a problem with `to_json` - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272043/how-to-get-custom-attributes-on-to-json-method) for a workaround.  If you need this in several places, you might want to refactor this code to a method in your Game class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24080/discussion-between-0xsina-and-pinnym)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you need to get games which are subscribed by some user and also apply some scope on these games?
May be this way would be acceptable

```
# extend user model with games collection
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # your code
    has_many :games, through: :subscriptions
end
```

And then in the controller (or anywhere you need) just call

```
@user.games.your_games_scope1.your_games_scope2.etc
```

Sorry if I misunderstood you